# Can anyone give me some idea about scamming and rippings off in Cairo of Egypt?

Tags: scams, cairo

What kinds of scamming and ripping off go on in Cairo?

I made several trips to New Delhi, India.

Is Cairo better or worse than New Delhi regarding scamming and ripping off?

Comment: What kind of scams did you face in New Delhi?

Answer (score 5):

A quick google search finds a series of usual scams; They are probably the same everywhere.

Fake taxi/uber, Fake tours/guides, Fake police, people asking to take pictures, "you drop something" pickpocket scam, people giving you gifts, people taking you to a fake/unsafe ATM machine.

People who speak English too fluently that comes out of nowhere to help you out. (see fake guides)

Comment: As an anecdote.  The best one I encountered was a waiter saying the bill was "50", when it was really "15".  But his accent in English was so thick that they sounded the same.  After he kept insisting that it was "50", we gave him 50, and never saw the 35 in change.

Comment: A couple more scam examples are described here https://upandgoneblog.com/how-to-avoid-the-cairo-scams/

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of advice about scam techniques which are similar everywhere.

One to watch out for is the 'softly' approach where they are at first friendly and want to buy you coffee etc. Then you are indebted to them and it gives them leverage when they make their pitch. That will inevitably be a request for money in some shape or form, and their next weapon is likely to be anger when you don't oblige.

The method is to groom you, and then use social mores as weapons to manipulate and fleece you. The way to respond is not to be unfriendly, or put up barriers, because you don't really want a defensive experience. As a tourist you can afford to pay for their coffee, so if you can turn the episode to your own advantage (for example to obtain local knowledge), so much the better.

Answer (score 1):

Three scams I've encountered while in Egypt, not only in Cairo:

1. people trying to sell you products or services claiming them to be "20 pounds". Then when you accept their service, they ask you to pay, but they claim they meant 20 British pounds, rather than 20 Egyptian pounds (~0.5 GBP). Similarly most shopkeepers at marketplaces will shout "one dollar" at travelers, but then say they actually meant 10 dollars or more.
2. people pretending to be friendly and helpful, then requesting a tip. As soon as you take your luggage off the baggage carousel, you'll have men walking up to you and offering to help you with your luggage. After carrying your bag for a few minutes they will ask you for money. You can expect similar ordeals from hotel staff and even toilet cleaning staff at the airports.
3. similar to 1), every now and then you'll see people offering you to get on the camel for a low price of few dollars at most. The ride will take less than a minute, and after that another person will come to get you off the camel, and they claim that you are incorrect, that the price is in tens of dollars and they will be very pushy about it.